# Compute $\iint_D{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{4a^2-x^2-y^2}}}d\sigma$,where $D$ is the circle:$(y+a)^2+x^2=a^2$(a>0)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

$$I=\iint_D{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{4a^2-x^2-y^2}}}d\sigma$$ where $D$ is the circle:$(y+a)^2+x^2=a^2$(a>0)

Use polar coordinates, then $$I=\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^{-2asin\theta}\frac{r^2}{\sqrt{4a^2-r^2}}dr$$
Use substitution $r=2asinu$ I got:
$$I=\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^{-\theta}4a^2(sinu)^2du=4a^2\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}(\frac14sin2\theta-\frac{\theta}{2})d\theta=-3a^2{\pi}^2$$

It's obivious that the answer shoule be a positive number but I got a negative one. I check my calculation several times and I think the last step may exit some problem, since when I use $\theta\in(\pi,2\pi)$ and $\theta\in(-\pi,0)$ I got two different answer. I think both interval could get the right answer if I did it correct.

Comment: It looks like something to do with your substitution $r= 2a \sin u$.  Notice that $\sqrt{4a^2 - r^2} = \sqrt{4a^2 \cos^2 u} = 2a |\cos u|$.  So, you need to take the sign of $\cos u$ into account.

Comment: @user197427 Good point. But if I use two different interval, as mentioned in my question. I will still got two different answer. So there is another problem here...

Comment: This issue comes about when you solve for the limit $r=-2a \sin \theta$.  You are using $2a \sin u = -2a \sin \theta$ which gives $\sin u = -\sin \theta$.  You cannot conclude $u = -\theta$ because there are more than one angle that give the same value of sine.  As per my previous comment, when doing a trigonometric substitution, you must be careful with the range of values of $u$ that you allow.

Comment: I don't quite have time to write a full answer right now, but I would suggest breaking up the integral into 2 parts, splitting the disk into a left and right half.

Comment: I think you can make your like easier by noting that the integrand is even in $y$.  Then you can simply flip the circle about the $x$ axis and just deal with positive numbers.